# Rich Text editor for both desktop and mobile browsers

Tags: wysiwyg

I need a rich text editor which works in both desktop and mobile browsers.
For example I am using [CLEdior](http://premiumsoftware.net/CLEditor/SimpleDemo) which works fine in desktop browsers but not safari or chrome in iOS and android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question [Best wysiwig editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191762/whats-the-best-wysiwyg-editor-currently-available-jquery-suppport-integration?rq=1)

I have used tinyMce. All the editors have had problems but all should work in the newer android/ios browsers as seen [here](http://caniuse.com/contenteditable).